# Substring of a Json value in Amp

Tags: javascript, substring, amp-list

How can I get a substring from a value in a Jason response.
Suppose I have a mydata value that I only need a few first characters of it.

Something like this 
{{mydata.substring(0,5)}}
Shall work, but it doesn't

I shall mention that this is in an amp-list

Comment: is this question really realated to amp? it looks to me as if you were using twig template not json response

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I am also facing the same issue. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below syntax and it's working fine for me.

```
'{{mydata}}'.substring(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should've been `{{mydata.substring(0,5)}}` instead of `{{my data.subString(0,5)}}`

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is `substring`, without camel case. 
Also, a quick reference:

```
String.slice( begin [, end ] )
String.substring( from [, to ] )
String.substr( start [, length ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below syntax and it's working fine for me.

`<div class="post-txt" [text]="'{{DisplayTxt}}'.slice(0,15)">`